# Local include path alias

Tags: php, include, sublimetext2, server-side-includes

This might be a silly question but it really annoys me. I began to program in Sublime Text 2 a short while ago, and really love it. One thing I just don't know how to set up is a way to include scripts that has to be included differently on the server.

On the server I have an include library, where I save all the "secure" files. This directory is placed outside of root, but using Apache, the PHP script can access the scripts simply by writing `include "filename.php";`. I really love this feature but it prevents me from receiving documentation and list over functions and variables. If I want to receive these informations, I have to include my classes/files like this: `include "../path/filename.php"`. I could do this, but then it won't work on the server.

I know this is silly, but I really think it is to much work to comment out a path variable every time I have to upload, for test and then uncomment it again when writing code. I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve, and please tell me if there is an easy solution. I mentioned Sublime Text 2 because I know there is a lot og packages (plugins) and perhaps somebody have thought about a plugin that automatically checks every include/require command and if no path is defined, it checks whether or not it is in the local folder and again if not, it checks a ".settings" file for a custom path I manually have defined. That would be nice :D

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php set_include_path is what you need. YOu can set it either in php.ini or in php

Comment: This will still require that I remove the `set_include_path` before I upload to the server.

Comment: no, you should set the correct include path in your php.ini both on your dev and prod machine, then use: include "filename.php"; and it should work on both machines

Comment: or you could also use set_include_path in your code, and the path you pass to it would be in config, and you have a different config file on dev, prod server